# IsAssignableFrom, IsInstanceOfType and the is keyword, what is the difference?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, casting

I have an extension method to safe casting objects, that looks like this:

```
public static T SafeCastAs<T>(this object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return default(T);

    // which one I should use?

    // 1. IsAssignableFrom
    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        return (T)obj;

    // 2. IsInstanceOfType
    if (typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(obj))
        return (T) obj;

    // 3. is operator
    if (obj is T)
        return (T) obj;

    return default(T);
}
```

As you can see, I have 3 choice, so which one I should to use? Actually what is the difference between `IsAssignableFrom`, `IsInstanceOfType`, and `is` operator?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You use whatever you have the information for.

If you have an instance and a static type you want to check against, use `is`.

If you don't have the static type, you just have a `Type` object, but you have an instance you want to check, use `IsInstanceOfType`.

If you don't have an instance and you just want to check the compatibility between a theoretical instance of a `Type` and another `Type`, use `IsAssignableFrom`.

But really is seems like you are just re-implementing the [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (except that yours would also work for non-nullable value types, which is usually not a big limitation).

Comment: There is an additional difference between IsAssignableFrom and IsInstanceOfType. There are some types where type A is assignable to type B even though type B is not an instance of type A. For example:

class B { }
class D : B { }
interface IGeneric<out T> { }

typeof(IGeneric<B>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IGeneric<D>); <== This expression is true
typeof(IGeneric<D>).IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IGeneric<B>); <== This expression is false

Answer (score 10):

I guess you're effectively implementing a version of the `as` operator that works with value types as well as reference types.

I'd go for:

```
public static T SafeCastAs<T>(this object obj)
{
    return (obj is T) ? (T) obj : default(T);
}
```

`IsAssignableFrom` works with types, and `is` works with instances. They will give you the same results in your case, so you should use the simplest version IMHO.

As for `IsInstanceOfType`:That is implemented in terms of `IsAssignableFrom`, so there will be no difference.

You can prove that by using Reflector to look at the definition of `IsInstanceOfType()`:

```
public virtual bool IsInstanceOfType(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return this.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should just go with "[as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" instead of your custom "SafeCastAs". But this will work only for classes (not structs), so if you want to use this method for structs as well I can get it.

Operator "is" basically gives you the same as Type.IsAssignableFrom, so you can keep only "is", it checks if you can safely cast obj to T, without exceptions. So it will cover both previous checks in your method. But you should be aware about that it does not check if you can assign obj to T, because of user defined conversions: [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keywords.

Comment: I'm not sure your assertion here is correct. `typeof(int)` returns a object of type `Type` so the first statement will fail since that `Type` object is obviously not an `int`. However, if you change the first statement to `a.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(3)` it will return true. I think you are using `IsInstanceOfType` wrong here.

Comment: @JeffBridgman true, my guess I just tried to show the difference of using these two methods, something like
```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?).IsInstanceOfType(null));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?).IsInstanceOfType(1));

Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)));
```
I'm going to remove some parts of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

These functions and operators have different meaning. If you have objects you can always get types. so you do not work on what you have, but you do what needs to be done.

When you are working with a class hierarchy differences are very clear.

Look at following example

```
      class ABase
        {

        }

        class BSubclass : ABase
        {

        }
    ABase aBaseObj = new ABase();
                BSubclass bSubclassObj = new BSubclass();

                ABase subObjInBaseRef = new BSubclass();
```

Different operations yield different results.

```
typeof(ABase).IsInstanceOfType(aBaseObj) = True

typeof(ABase).IsInstanceOfType(bSubclassObj) = True

typeof(ABase).IsInstanceOfType(bSubclassObj) = True

typeof(BSubclass).IsInstanceOfType(aBaseObj) = False

bSubclassObj is ABase = True

aBaseObj is BSubclass = False

subObjInBaseRef is BSubclass = True

subObjInBaseRef is BSubclass = True

typeof(ABase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BSubclass))  = True

typeof(BSubclass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ABase))= False
```

In case on no hierarchy, may be everything was same.
But if you work with hierarchy, `IsAssignableFrom` , is , and `IsInstanceOfType` yield different results.

There are more possible combinations that could be tried. For example, you can introduce a class C which is not related in anyway with existing classes in this example.