# Implementing Enumerable.OfType<T> with Type instance argument

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, types

I'm trying to implement an alternative to OfType where you specify the desired type as a Type instance argument instead of using type parametrization but I'm not sure what the 'correct way' to implement it is. This is what I have so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Type type)
{
    return enumerable.Where(element => type.IsInstanceOfType(element));
}
```

I initially started out with the code below, but realized it would not support inheritance...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Type type)
{
    return enumerable.Where(element => element.GetType() == type);
}
```

Then I thought about comparing base-types for few seconds before thinking that would probably be a bad idea.

So my question is will the code at the top always return the same result as OfType given the types provided are the same? In other words will the collections `parametrizedFiltered` and `typeInstanceFiltered` in the code example below contain the same elements or am I way off?

```
IEnumerable<InterfaceType> someCollection = BlackBox.GetCollection();
IEnumerable<DerivedType> parametrizedFiltered = someCollection.OfType<DerivedType>();
IEnumerable<InterfaceType> typeInstanceFiltered = someCollection.OfType(typeof(DerivedType));
```

Comment: You might take a look at `IsAssignableFrom` for 'deep' checking with inheritence.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I think `IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())` is equivalent to `IsInstanceOfType(x)` when you ignore the `null` case. Caching the result of `IsAssignableFrom` might improve performance though.

Comment: Array co-variance and nullable value types behave identically. Interface co-variance should work as well.

Comment: So you basically are asking if `obj is TResult` is the same as `typeof(TResult).IsInstanceOfType(obj)`

Comment: The main difference is that `OfType` returns an `IEnumerable` of the type you specify where as what you are doing will return an `IEnumerable` of the orginial type just with the ones that don't "match" filtered.

Comment: @juharr Yes, unfortunately it is unavoidable that the IEnumerable will be of the original type but I am willing to live with that...

Comment: @IvanStoev I found the linked duplicate answer a few seconds before this one was marked as duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering whether your implementation will give the same results as `Enumerable.OfType<>` then, it will.

`Enumerable.OfType<>` uses `is` as its implementation, and as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853159/isassignablefrom-isinstanceoftype-and-the-is-keyword-what-is-the-difference) shows, the `is` keyword will give the same results a `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`.

The other piece of information you need is that `IsInstanceOfType()` is implemented using `IsAssignableFrom`:

```
public virtual bool IsInstanceOfType(Object o)
{
    if (o == null)
        return false;

    // No need for transparent proxy casting check here
    // because it never returns true for a non-rutnime type.

    return IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
}
```

The test code below will print

```
Demo.Base
Demo.Derived
```

which shows that your original code does indeed work with inheritance:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Base {}
    public class Derived : Base {}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            object[] array = {"String", new Base(), new Derived(), 12345};

            foreach (var item in OfType(array, typeof(Base)))
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Type type)
        {
            return enumerable.Where(element => type.IsInstanceOfType(element));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because `IsInstanceOfType()` is implemented using `IsAssignableFrom` then you can write your method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Type type)
{
    return enumerable.Where(element => type.IsAssignableFrom(element.GetType()));
}
```

Comment: By *close* you mean *identical*?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Oops I was looking at his second code sample. Yes, I guess this answer is redundant. :) Will edit.

Comment: @SindriJóelsson Since `Type.IsInstanceOfType()` will give the same results as the `is` operator, and since `Enumerable.OfType<>` uses `is` for its implementation, then the two methods will give the same results. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Your question was `So my question is will the code at the top always return the same result as OfType given the types provided are the same?` and the answer therefore is `Yes, it will`, because `is` and `Type.IsInstanceOfType()` effectively work the same way.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted then.