# Can `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())` be safely rewritten as `x is T`?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, system.type

> **Note: This is not a duplicate of ["Use of IsAssignableFrom and “is” keyword in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013694/use-of-isassignablefrom-and-is-keyword-in-c-sharp).** That other question asks about `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type))`, where `type` is not an `object` but a `Type`.
>
> This seems trivial — I can hear you saying, "Just call `x.GetType()`!" — but due to the COM-related corner case mentioned below, that call causes problems, which is why I'm asking about the rewrite.

… or are there rare special cases where the two might give different results?

I stumbled upon a type check of the form:

```
typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType())
```

where `TValue` is a generic type parameter (without any constraints) and `value` is an `object`.

I am not entirely sure whether it is safe to rewrite the above simply as:

```
value is TValue
```

To my current knowledge, the two tests are equivalent with the exception of COM objects. `is` should trigger a proper `QueryInterface`, while `IsAssignableFrom` might get confused by the `__ComObject` RCW wrapper type and report a false negative.

Are there any other differences between `is` and the shown use of `IsAssignableFrom`?

Comment: I *think* that's fine - and note that the JIT can actually do much better tricks with the `is` version (for value-types at least: it can throw away entire chunks of code while it JITs, since it knows what the result of `is` will be). If in doubt: add unit tests that check it for combinations you expect to see.

Comment: @Reniuz that question seems to mostly focus on the object vs type semantics, which aren't the issue here

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for the reply. I'd love to add unit tests, but therein lies the problem. I need to expect anything and everything. The code in question is found in a very widespread library (Moq) that gets exposed to pretty much everything possible. I probably wouldn't know at which point my unit tests cover all possibilities.

Comment: I don't get the belly-ache.  If you have confidence that IsAssignableFrom() does what you want it to do then just use it.  Perf is irrelevant in a unit test and brevity is irrelevant in a library.

Comment: @HansPassant: `IsAssignableFrom` does what I want, *mostly*. I found one case where it fails (namely with COM objects), which is why I'd like to get rid of it. But I want to be sure that by changing the test to use the `is` operator, I'm not introducing other problems.

Comment: There is at least one corner case where `is` and `IsAssignableFrom` returns different results: `typeof(int[]).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(uint[]))` returns true but `new uint[] { } is int[]` returns false

Comment: @Nuf: And `((object)new uint[0])) is int[]` is true! Your example is one of the cases that the C# compiler tries to optimize but gets wrong. I'm surprised that bug has never been fixed.

Comment: @EricLippert: Would I be right in assuming that we've got a difference here between what the CLR allows and what C# allows (without any type casting)? `new uint[0] is int[]` gives us C#'s perspective (`false`, therefore `uint[] uints = new int[0];` is illegal), while `typeof(int[]).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(uint[]))` gives us the CLR's perspective (`true`, which is why `uint[] uints = (uint[])(object)new int[0];` doesn't throw).

Comment: @Nuf: if you'd like to turn the few comments on the point you've raised into an answer, I'd happily upvote & accept it.

Comment: @stakx: That's correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are more cases where `is` and `IsAssignableFrom` returns different results, not just the one you mentioned for COM objects. For pair of array types with elements of type *ElementType1* and *ElementType2*, where underlaying types of both element types are integer types of the same size but with opposite signedness, then

`typeof(ElementType1[]).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ElementType2[]))` returns **true** but

`new ElementType2[0] is ElementType1[]` returns **false**

Specifically this includes arrays with these pairs of their element types:

- *byte* / *sbyte*, *short* / *ushort*, *int* / *uint*, *long* / *ulong*
- *IntPtr* / *UIntPtr*
- any combination of enum type and either integer type or another enum type as long as underlaying types are of the same size
- any combination of *IntPtr* / *UIntPtr* / *int* / *uint* in 32-bit process
- any combination of *IntPtr* / *UIntPtr* / *long* / *ulong* in 64-bit process

This is due to differences in type system of C# and CLR as explained in

- [Why does my C# array lose type sign information when cast to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1178973/1286670)
- [Why does “int[] is uint[] == true” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/593730/1286670)
- [Why is covariance of value-typed arrays inconsistent?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/24/why-is-covariance-of-value-typed-arrays-inconsistent/)

Different results of `is` and `IsAssignableFrom` in all cases mentioned above results from the fact that for `new ElementType2[0] is ElementType1[]` C# compiler simply emits `False` at compile-time (because it sees no way that for example int[] can be cast to uint[] as these are completly different types from C# perspective), completly omitting any runtime type checks. Fortunately casting array to object `((object)new ElementType2[0]) is ElementType1[]` forces compiler to emit `isinst` IL instruction, which performs runtime type-check, that returns results consistent with `IsAssignableFrom`. This is also true for cases where target type is generic parameter, because it's type is not known at compile-time and C# compiler must emit `isinst`. So if you intend to replace `IsAssignableFrom` by `is` only in places where target type is generic parameter (as suggested in question title), I believe that these differences does not metter for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int? bob = null;

        Test(bob);
    }

    private static void Test<T>(T bob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bob is T);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(bob));
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(bob.GetType()));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is an example where they act slightly differently (since bob is null).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853213/34092 may be of interest.

Other than that (and the other exceptions you mention) they do appear to be equivalent.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I knew about this one already. But you're right, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my apologies!

Comment: My bad. Thanks for taking the time to reply.