# C# how to check if a variable of type object can be cast to a struct type?

Tags: c#

In C#, if I have a variable of type `object`, how can I check if I can cast it to a type `T` which is a value type? The `as` operator doesn't work, since T is a value type, and `o.GetType().Equals(typeof(T))` just checks if object is a boxed variable of type T, but not if it is something that can be cast to T.

Comment: "...just checks if object is a boxed variable of type T, but not if it is something that can be cast to T." For structs, aren't these two things equivalent? Can you give an example of such a `T`, i.e. `o.GetType().Equals(typeof(T))` is false, but you can cast the object to `T`.

Comment: @Sweeper no, if it's a boxed float it would return a different result than for a boxed double, even though both can be cast to either one

Comment: @user1282931: No, a boxed `double` can't be cast to `float` or vice versa. There are a *few* cases where you can cast to a different type (e.g. `uint` vs `int`, or enums) but in general, you can only unbox to the original boxed type.

Comment: @user1282931 Can you use the `is` operator like `if (o is double d)`?

Comment: Umm... no, you can't cast a boxed `float` to `double`. Try `object o = 1f; double d = (double)o;`. Unless you mean something different?

Comment: @JonSkeet What do you mean by `uint` vs `int`? Casting a boxed `int` to `uint` or viceversa throws `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: I would assume that `as` would not work even if `T` was reference type, cause _The as operator considers only reference, nullable, boxing, and unboxing conversions. You cannot use the as operator to perform a user-defined conversion._ ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator))

Comment: @V0ldek: Whoops - for the `uint`/`int` case I was thinking about arrays. (The C# compiler won't let you convert an `int[]` to `uint[]`, but the CLR is happy to do so.) It *does* still work with unboxing int vs enum though: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/bbe290432a665937be0a18841d4e1f2c

Comment: discussing particular system/.Net implemented value types misses the point entirely.  It is legal to define a struct type with an implicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
object obj = "wer";
var isCompatible = typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

```
object obj = "wer";
typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(obj)
```

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinstanceoftype?view=netcore-3.1

Or

```
object obj = "wer";
obj is T;
```

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Or

```
object obj = "wer";
typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())
```

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netcore-3.1

However you need to note about the differences between `IsAssignableFrom` and `IsInstanceOfType` and `is`. Read more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/497001/1666800

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853224/1666800